# restore windows 7 bootloader after installing Centos

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, operating-system, centos6

Ok, That, I had Windows 7 on hard disk, and have free logical disk, so I decided install Centos 6.4 to here. But after installing I see boot shows `Centos 6.4` and `Other`. If I choose `Other` , I can't load windows. I remember that, when installing Centos I choose default boot as windows boot.

So, now, What I should do for repair windows bootloader ?

Edit:

```
[root@dhcppc0 grub]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000953c6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1       15678   125931520    5  Extended
/dev/sda2   *       15678       15691      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3           15691       36189   164645888   42  SFS
/dev/sda4           36189      121602   686080728   42  SFS
/dev/sda5               1          65      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda6              65        7897    62914560   83  Linux
/dev/sda7            7897       15156    58306560   83  Linux
/dev/sda8           15156       15678     4193280   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: What boot loader do CentOS have? Grub? You'll probably need to add Windows entry manually.

Comment: Yes, Grub. but how me add Windows entry manually?

Comment: Well I don't know in CentOS, but they are several tutorials on the web. You'll need to modify a config file.

Comment: I don't see any NTFS partition there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem once a few years back.
Here's how i fixed the problem:

Insert the windows installation disc and click through until you reach the screen with the "install now" button. But instead of clicking that button, click on "repair your computer" further down. Then choose "use recovery tools..", then click on the command prompt button.

In CMD type: `bootrec /fixmbr`

This should repair the master boot record.

Comment: I'd try this, but windows still doesn't boot.

Comment: And if it worked then CentOS wouldn't boot.  Windows doesn't play nicely with other OSs - you have to install Windows first, then install the other OS, then fix Grub so that it recognizes both.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows 7 Boot Loader Problems

1. Insert the Windows 7 installation DVD OR Bootable USB
2. Select **Repair your computer** option windows takes some time to load what ever Error
   got just click **OK** Or **NEXT**
3. Once you have reached the **System Recovery Options** screen click
   **Command Prompt** to continue

---

Enter following command

> Bootrec /Fixmbr

if not works then try

> Bootsect /nt60 c: